# How to find the logical error in this PyGame code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pygame

This is an early prototype for a game I'm currently working on for a project. However it seems that I have reached a roadblock where the player character cannot be displayed as you can see in the code I have created a class for the player

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,480))#initialises the game window
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello world")
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')

#player class
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 64
        self.height = 64
        self.standing = True
        self.left = False
        self.right = True
        self.vel = 5
        self.jumping = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
    def move(self,x,y):
        self.k = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
        if self.k[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.x  > 0 + self.vel + self.width:
            left = True
            right = False
            self.standing = False
            self.x -= vel
        elif self.k[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.x  < 500-self.vel-self.width:
              self.right = True
              self.left = False
              self.standing = False
              self.x += vel
        else:
            self.standing = True       
        if self.jumping:#checks if users jumping intiating jump
            if self.k[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                if self.jumpCount >= -10:
                    neg = 1
                if self.JumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                self.y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
                self.jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                self.jumping = False
                self.jumpCount = 10

    def draw(self,win,move):
        wLeft = pygame.image.load('runningleft.png')
        wRight = pygame.image.load('running.png')
        char = pygame.image.load('idleright.png')
        if not(self.standing):
            if self.left:
                win.blit(wleft,(self.x,self.y))
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(wright,(self.x,self.y))
        else:
            win.blit(char,(self.x,self.y))

        pygame.display.update()



pygame.display.update()
wizard = player(50,450)
run = True
while run:#main game loop
   for event in pygame.event.get():#loops through a list of keyboard or mouse events
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False
   wizard.move(wizard.x,wizard.y)
   wizard.draw(win)
   win.blit(bg,(0,0))
   pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

The background is shown in the main game window, whereas the character isn't. As stated before I attempted to transition the project into OOP which is where my code stopped. How can I diagnose the problems in my code?

Comment: When I duplicate your code, I get an error that `wizard.draw(win)` is missing the required argument `move`. From this method, `def draw(self,win,move):`. Maybe you could post the entire code, with all the `jpg` in a dropbox or something?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And [this post about asking help ASAP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADjYKACTRotcKL_1bliUcloAQIiHRJ8E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The order of your instructions is wrong. You need to draw the player (`wizard`) after drawing the background and before updating the display:

1. `win.blit(bg,(0,0))`
2. `wizard.draw(win)`
3. `pygame.display.update()`

```py
wizard = player(50,450)

#main game loop
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    wizard.move(wizard.x,wizard.y)        
    
    win.blit(bg,(0,0))
    wizard.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
```

It is sufficient to update the display once at the end of the loop, so remove `pygame.display.update()` from `player.draw`. Multiple updates to the display cause flickering. See [Why is the PyGame animation is flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62120723/why-is-the-pygame-animation-is-flickering/62120776#62120776)