# Why is the PyGame animation is flickering

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

So I run the code and it just starts glitching out. I am new to pygame.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
# Screen (Pixels by Pixels (X and Y (X = right and left Y = up and down)))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
running = True
# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
# Player Icon/Image
playerimg = pygame.image.load('Player.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480

def player(x, y):
    # Blit means Draw
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))


# Game loop (Put all code for pygame in this loop)
while running:
    screen.fill((225, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    # if keystroke is pressed check whether is right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print("Left arrow is pressed")

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print("Right key has been pressed")


            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print("kEYSTROKE RELEASED")

    # RGB (screen.fill) = red green blue

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

The image is not the glitching one as I was not able to post a video but it is what my code does

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by multiple calls to [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update). An update of the display at the end of the application loop is sufficient. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering.

Remove all calls to `pygame.display.update()` from your code, but call it once at the end of the application loop:

```py
while running:
    screen.fill((225, 0, 0))
    # pygame.display.update() <---- DELETE

    # [...]

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

If you update the display after `screen.fill()`, the display will be shown filled with the background color for a short moment. Then the player is drawn (`blit`) and the display is shown with the player on top of the background.