# pygame" screen.fill command" ,where do i place it?

Tags: python, pygame

i am lately facing difficulty in screen.fill command , my program runs fine but the characte is jittery and sometims wont appear on the screen  ,i have tried placing the command from different location  in code . it also sometimes leaves trails behind it
...
import pygame

```
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
#creation of screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
#window title
# game.display.set_caption("space invaders")
#player coordinates
playerX = 360
playerY = 480
#player image
playerimg = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
#player change distance
playerX_change = 0

#drawing player on screen
def player(x, y):

pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.update()
screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))

#game loop
running = True

while running == True:
#event system
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
#exit function
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

            player(playerX, playerY)
#arrows key press detection or movement system
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        player(playerX,playerY)
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -0.3
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0.3

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:

            playerX_change = 0
#movement
    playerX += playerX_change
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the screen once, before grawing the objects on the screen. Actually you call `screen.fill`  in the event loop. The event loop is executed once for each event. Move `screen.fill` from the event loop to the application loop. The application loop is executed once per frame.

```py
while running == True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))        # insert
#event system
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #screen.fill((0, 0, 0))    # delete
#exit function
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    # [...]
```

Additionally update the display only once after drawing all the objects. See [Why is the PyGame animation is flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62120723/why-is-the-pygame-animation-is-flickering/62120776#62120776).